can't compare `solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey` with `spl_memo::solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey`
I'm trying to run a CPI example of Raydium AMM
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cpi-example/blob/master/amm-cpi/
All settings are the same as in GitHub repo.
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = "0.29.0"
amm-anchor = { git = "https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions", package = "amm-anchor" }
solana-program = ">=1.16, <1.18"

It seems that dependencies versions are wrong.
Cargo.lock
[[package]]
name = "solana-program"
version = "1.16.25"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
...

[[package]]
name = "solana-program"
version = "2.0.11"
source = "registry+https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"

I found that people are playing with versions to solve this problem, but since my experience with Rust and Solana is very low I don't know what versions they are using.
And how do they downgrade dependencies that are automatically loaded from other dependencies?

edit: compiled the amm-cpi example using the versions below with no errors.
anchor-cli 0.28.0
solana-cli 1.17.34 (src:b04a806c; feat:3746964731, client:SolanaLabs)

It's not just what's in your Cargo.toml you might also need to
update your lock file,
In a previous project, downgrading one dependency causes a chain reaction where you'll need to downgrade a bunch of other crates which is impossible to know beforehand the ones that'll be affected.
Here is a working lock file https://gist.github.com/jim4067/d251f8b93dd28864c497824ae22e39bd

I've installed the same environment as yours. Can you please share the command you use to build amm-cpi since whenever I run [anchor build] it updates Cargo.lock file

delete the target folder update your lock file with the one in the gist, save and then build

Thanks for your time, but still there is a problem
my@MBP amm-cpi % rm -rf target
my@MBP amm-cpi % rm Cargo.lock
my@MBP % cp Cargo.lock.Jimii Cargo.lock
my@MBP % anchor build
error: package num_enum_derive v0.7.3 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.70.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p num_enum_derive@0.7.3 --precise ver
where ver is the latest version of num_enum_derive supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
You removed num_enum_derive v0.7.3, but the build overwrite Cargo.lock

Looks like you are going to update the crates that are causing the issues. Start with cargo update -p num_enum@0.7.3 --precise 0.7.0

That's because of the requirement of spl-token-2022 which was overwritten in a lock file after anchor build. Can you please share your Cargo.toml file?

Rust doesn't strictly adhere to semver rules, https://gist.github.com/jim4067/ddaff45f590bb63b803e9e70bc7a427f

This answer helped. Thanks
